# Why is my abstract JSON object not being parsed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I just spent a long time trying to work this one out, so I'm posting here in case anyone else makes the same mistake as me.

So, to replicate the situation, I just had a few classes with basic inheritance:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public int SomethingSpecial { get; set; }
}

public class Baz : Foo
{
    public string SomethingMundane { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to be able to take a json string, and parse back a concrete implementation of `Foo`, without knowing beforehand which type the json represents. JSON.Net handles this, by using a *$type* variable to look up the type of the object:

```
{
    "$type": "MyNamespace.Bar",
    "Name": "Resources",
    "SomethingSpecial": 42
}
```

When deserializing the object, you may want to specify the type handling options, and a custom binder, in the JsonSerializerSettings, but that's optional.

The problem I ran into was that when posting the json from a web client, the object was not being deserialized, instead either throwing an exception, or in the case of a POST parameter in ASP.Net, the value was just coming in as `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Newtonsoft.Json (at least, the version I'm using - 9.0.1) expects the *$type* element to be the **first** element of the object, and will ignore it when it is in any other position. So the following json, while technically equivalent to the json in the question, will not work:

```
{
    "Name": "Resources",
    "$type": "MyNamespace.Bar",
    "SomethingSpecial": 42
}
```

There *is* a setting for this, although it may have a performance impact:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    // $type no longer needs to be first
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
}
```

It's worth noting that if you're using JavaScript's `JSON.stringify` function, properties are generally written out in the order they were first assigned to the object, so you could also make sure the first thing you do is assign *$type*.